# StaleDataError: while updating a row in a table with error : expected to update 1 row(s); 2 were matched

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to update a row in a table based on some filters. I could get the `row_object` and i could update it if the number of rows is one and if more than one it throws `StaleDataError` while saving the session.
I have 2 rows in my db

Following is the code..

```
@require_context
def travel_update(context, travel_id, region, resource):
    with write_session() as session:
        time_now = timeutils.utcnow()

         travel_ref = session.query(models.Region_travel). \
             filter_by(id=travel_id, region=region, resource=resource). \
             first()
        if not travel_ref:
            raise exception.idNotFound(travel_id=travel_id)
        travel_ref.status = "failed"
        travel_ref.updated_at = time_now
        travel_ref.save(session)
        return travel_ref
```

Comment: "if the number of rows is one and if more than one" if you want to update this two rows than you have to iterate over them because sqlalchemy cant know which one going to update. If you are saying this is not the problem. I will ask you `travel_ref = ... .first()` and will give you one row and you can update, if here with `first()` you are getting `StaleDataError` this error than maybe you should check here to see what cause this error http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/exceptions.html#sqlalchemy.orm.exc.StaleDataError

Comment: Tq i kept a pdb there it is not throwing error at 
" "travel_ref.status = "failed" " rather it is failing at this step "travel_ref.save(session)"

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem (primarily due to my lack of attention-to-detail). The database table `key` was different from the `key` defined in my sql_alchemy models (for that table), which lead sql_alchemy to use a column (the `old key`) that matched more than one row in the database during the update step of the transaction.

Updating the sql_alchemy model `primary key` to the actual db `primary key` fixed the problem.

Comment: Faced the exact same issue today. @jazzTheJackRabbit thank you so much for your answer here!